The "betrayal" of Jesus in the Gnosticism
According to Gospel of Judas, why did Judas hand over Jesus to Roman authorities? Did Jesus asked him himself to do so? If yes, then why did Jesus needed this? Did he just want to escape the material world ASAP?

The 'Gospel of Judas' Wikipedia Given that it includes late 2nd-century theology, it is widely thought to have been composed in the 2nd century (prior to 180 AD) by Gnostic Christians.[1] The only copy of it known to exist is a Coptic language text that has been carbon dated to 280 AD, plus or minus 60 years

Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the community of users to maintain the integrity of the site. Welcome to SE-C.
